# Android send lat/lang of one device to other App

Tags: android

Hello everyone i have two different Apps 'A' and 'B' installed on different devices. I want to send the lat/lang of one device to the other using my apps. How i will do it? I don't want to use my own server for communication. How i can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can you Parse db for storing data.
 parse.com

Comment: its mean i have to put all my server side data on cloud?

Comment: i want to reduce my own server load. my apps are already using my own server, but i have to send lat/lang periodically and by various user that's why i want to use another method instead of my own server for sending lat/lang

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy without your own Server, **since the IP address of your clients is not always globally reachable**, my suggestions are:

1. Send Email or SMS
2. Use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
3. Give [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html) a try

Comment: i want to reduce my own server load. my apps are already using my own server, but i have to send lat/lang periodically and by various user that's why i want to use another method instead of my own server for sending lat/lang

Comment: but i want to track in real time so that i can show that lat/lang on other device map

Comment: sorry i updated my answer Google Cloud Messaging (Push) can help you.

Comment: how i can directly send lat/lang from app to GCM without involving my server??